# saving image in database and show in view laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, image

i want to store image in my database as client agreement but i can't save any thing in database just the path i give manually here is what i have done

controller :

```
 $filename = $request->file('agreement')->store('public/images');

    $client = Client::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'fax'=>$request->fax,
        'adrress1'=>$request->adrress1,  
        'telephone1'=>$request->telephone1,  
        'client_type'=>$request->client_type,
        'sellpercent'=>$request->sellpercent,
        'agreement'=>'uploads/agreement/'. $filename,
```

view :

```
.
.
.
<div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">test image</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="file" name="agreement" class="form-control-plaintext">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised legitRipple">submit</button>
```

with this code i get this error on store function

```
Call to a member function store() on null
```

and if i remove store function i just save null in database

Comment: have you used `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag?

Comment: emmm no let me try that

Comment: aa nope yet again i get this error Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: can you post entire form?

Comment: i am saving the file now but i cant find the picture i mean its not uploading it to files any idea ?

Comment: you mean that the file name is reflected in the database but it is not showing in your storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag as an attribute.

Secondly, 
replace `$filename = $request->file('agreement')->store('public/images');` with `$filename = $request->file('agreement')->move('public/images');`

Hope that helps.